# OAuth2.0 For SPA + Backend?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am in the process of learning OAuth 2.0 for use with a SPA application that also has a separate backend service. The SPA is served by webpack and only makes AJAX calls to the backend for various data and actions; the backend under the current setup has no way to preprocess requests (like the login callback). As such, I'm looking at doing the Implicit Flow with PKCE.

I'm using the MSAL library for react, and I am able to login successfully on the front-end of the application. My question is: How should I go about propagating the credentials to the backend? Do I just submit the id + access tokens to the backend and preserve them for as long as they are valid?  What's the best way to handle refreshing tokens?

Also, is there a good API for storing/using the id and access tokens for Ruby on Rails? Thanks!